# extract function with variable arguments

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Given I have the function:

```
void A::IAmCool(int x, ...)
{
        va_list args; 
        va_start (args, x);   
        va_end (args);
}
```

How do I pass var-args from one function to another? I'm looking for something like this:

```
void A::extractedFunction() /* this doesn't work */
{
        va_list args; 
        va_start (args, ?????);   
        va_end (args);
}

void A::IAmCool(int x, ...)
{
        extractedFunction();
}
```

Is this even possible? I have tried making the function inline but that doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know what "extract" means here.  Like, at all.

Comment: @djechlin: I'm going to guess is referring to the Eclipse-style refactoring facility.

Comment: this might help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring

Comment: @PaulNikonowicz: Can your question be better phrased as "how do I pass var-args from one function to another?"?

Comment: I think that would be a valid edit

Comment: can you not just pass the va_list?

Comment: I bet you can find an example if you look through this source: http://www.ijs.si/software/snprintf/

Comment: you can probably pass the list, but i was hoping to pass all of it

Comment: I would strongly advise you look into variadic templates if you have C++11.

Comment: If you are using C++, do not write variadic functions.  End of story.  Variadic functions completely lack type safety.  There are other patterns (e.g., what the IO streams or Boost Format do) that are far superior.  [If you have a compiler with variadic templates support, then that's a different matter altogether, but you've said that you're using Visual C++, which does not support variadic templates.]

Comment: @JamesMcNellis, oh, I'm not too familiar on what VC++ supports :/ That's too bad as variadic templates are pretty awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual pattern is to implement your main workhorse function taking a valist, and the variadic function only as "decoration". Then you can use the main function directly from third-party call sites. Example:

```
#include <cstdarg>

int vgizmo(int a, std::va_list ap)
{
    // main implementation here!
}

int gizmo(int a, ...)  // interface function
{
    std::va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, a);
    int r = vgizmo(a, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return r;
}

void some_other_stuff(bool q, char const * fmt, ...)
{
    std::va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);

    // ...

    int b = vgizmo(x, ap);   // third parties use vgizmo directly

    // ...

    va_end(ap);
}
```

Comment: See `vprintf()` for a widespread example of this approach... on linux, just `man vprintf`.  And one important thing to note is that in spite of looking like a pass-by-value function call, `va_arg()` is a macro that modifies the `va_list`.  In other words, you can't pass the same `va_list` into two different functions without a `va_end()` and another `va_start()` in between.  Also, the linux man page `man stdarg` is pretty good.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland: You can use `va_copy` to create multiple copies of a given valist.

Answer (score 0):

In C-like languages (C, C++, Objective-C etc.) you can't directly pass variadic arguments. However, you may (and if you're developing an external library, or you just want to facilitate the work of reverse engineers you should) supply a non-variadic version of your function, and make the variadic one just wrap it, so that you can pass down as many arguments as needed to your function -- using `va_list`. Example:

```
// variadic function
void variadic_func(int nargs, ...)
{
    // just wrap the non-variadic one
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, nargs);
    non_variadic_func(nargs, args);
    va_end(args);
}

// non-variadic function
void non_variadic_func(int nargs, va_list args)
{
    // do what you want with `args'
}

// you can pass down varargs like this:
void outmost_caller_func(int nargs, ...)
{
    // since you can't pass down the `...', you create a va_list argument list
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, nargs);
    // and call the non-variadic version of your function, just like the wrapper
    // would do (anyway, the wrapper is only for convenience...)
    non_variadic_func(nargs, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```