# Calling a variadic function with an unknown number of parameters

Tags: c++, c, variadic-functions

Say I have a function that takes a variable number of parameters: I want to call this function from somewhere else, building the list of parameters, but without knowing in advance how many parameters I'll need.

Sorry that's not well explained, hopefully this code makes my question clearer:

```
void foo(int n, ...) {
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl,n);

    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
      // Do something to each passed variable
    }
}
```

That function's being called from this one:

```
void bar(int howManyParams) {

  // Here I want to call foo() with howManyParams parameters
  // (values are irrelevant for the question)
  // 
  // I.e. for howManyParams = 1, we should call foo(0)
  //      for howManyParams = 2, we should call foo(0,0)
  //      for howManyParams = 3, we should call foo(0,0,0)
  // etc.
  //

}
```

Comment: Using array here would be much more appropriate...

Comment: Generally there's some kind of convention for the caller to denote how many variables the function should pull off of the stack.  For example, printf() and its variants have a format string, where there are specific format markers corresponding to passed arguments.  Or sometimes, the convention is that a specific value, such as zero, will mark the end of the arguments.  It's up to you to come up with such a convention.

Comment: Although, since your question is tagged C++, you might consider passing a container with a known size, such as a std::vector, instead of relying on variadic arguments.

Comment: Maybe [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10761422)?

Comment: Is the number of arguments endless or limited to some small-ish finite number like 4,10,100?

Comment: Thanks for the comments about terminating variables but, unless I'm misunderstanding, those would help me at the receiving function, `Foo`. It's `Bar` that's got me stumped!

Comment: @DanKorn could do, but this code runs on an embedded device so I'd rather not to keep the footprint down.

Comment: C is pass by value. It does not pass variables (i.e. references).

Comment: @CharlieB Note that C only specifies that a function accept up to 127 arguments.  Pass that and code may not compile.

Comment: If you really try building the parameter-list at run-time, that is not possible. It is also a debugging nightmare. As the arguments seem to of the same type, what is the problem with passing an array (resp. a pointer to the first entry)? Younds like an XY-problem to me. What do you actually want to accomplish?

Comment: @Olaf I put all ints here for simplicity, but in general it could be otherwise. But it seems like I may need a rethink, maybe build a simple `parameters` object and pass that instead

Comment: If you want to just write C and not use C++, then don't tag the question with C++.  If you are using C++ anyway, why not use it?  Or, just pass a simple C array, that's still easier than dealing with variadic arguments.

Comment: @CharlieB: If the arguments have different types, please answer a simple question: how does the caller know which type each argument has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually building a variable-length argument list at run-time -- which is what I'm pretty sure you're trying to do -- is pretty tricky.  There's no way to do it at all in Standard C, but there are various tricks you can try.

Perhaps the best is the "Foreign Function Interface Library" at http://sourceware.org/libffi/ .

See also question 15.13 in the C FAQ list: http://c-faq.com/varargs/invvarargs.html

---

See also these previous Stackoverflow questions:
[C late binding with unknown arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34885868/c-late-binding-with-unknown-arguments)
[How to call functions by their pointers passing multiple arguments in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206865/how-to-call-functions-by-their-pointers-passing-multiple-arguments-in-c)

Comment: If that is what OP wants (I suspect you are right), it becomes a nightmare of debugging.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was asking. Thanks for the tips, I'll have a rethink to avoid doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a terminating parameter, it may be NULL, or something else, that should never appear in your real arguments. Inside your function you can loop over the arguments until you reach a terminating NULL or any other value you choose to signal the end.

Comment: See the `execl` function for an example of this kid of function.

Comment: How does that help implementing `bar`?

Comment: Looks like `n` is meant for that.

Answer (score 0):

If a special value cannot be reserved to indicate the end of the list, pass 2 arguments for each parameter.  Tad wasteful but does allow code to be sequentially automatically generated without value restrictions.

```
foo(0);
foo(1, Params1, 0);
foo(1, Params1, 1, Params2, 0);
foo(1, Params1, 1, Params2, 1, Params3, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to do at runtime what the OP asked is probably by relying on standard containers like `std::vector`s and the others.

Anyway, for the sake of completeness, here is an example of how a variadic pack of parameters can be created at compile time and used later to invoke a function:

```
#include<utility>
#include<tuple>
#include<iostream>

auto params(std::index_sequence<0>) {
    return std::tuple<std::size_t>{};
}

template<std::size_t I, std::size_t... O>
auto params(std::index_sequence<I, O...>) {
    auto tup = std::tuple<std::size_t>{ sizeof...(O) };
    auto seq = std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(O)>{};
    return std::tuple_cat(tup, params(seq));
}

void foo() {
    std::cout << "done." << std::endl;
}

template<typename Arg, typename... Args>
void foo(Arg &&arg, Args&&... args) {
    std::cout << "arg: " << arg << ", still to be elaborated: " << sizeof...(Args) << std::endl;
    foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<typename... Args, std::size_t... Indexes>
void invoke(std::tuple<Args...> &tup, std::index_sequence<Indexes...>) {
    foo(std::get<Indexes>(tup)...);
}

template<std::size_t N>
void bar(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N> size) {
    auto seq = std::make_index_sequence<N>{};
    auto tup = params(seq);
    invoke(tup, seq);
}

int main() {
    bar(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 3>{});
    bar(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 5>{});
}
```

Unfortunately, for it must be completely resolved at compile time, the argument for the `bar` function cannot be a `std::size_t` for itself.
Instead, a `std::integral_constant` can be used to do that.

Answer (score 0):

When I've need to do something like this, I got it to work with a "switch-fan".

```
switch( n ){
case 1:  foo(0);     break;
case 2:  foo(0,0);   break;
case 3:  foo(0,0,0); break;
}
```